# update from d3.js version 3 to version 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I switched my d3.js code from v3 to v4 recently but in the newer version the axis is showing but the graph is not.
my older code was

```
var margin = {top: 4, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - 12*margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - 45*margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width-40], 0.1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var color_range = [$('#correct_h').css('background-color'),
                   $('#correct_m').css('background-color'),
                   $('#correct_l').css('background-color'),
                   $('#wrong_h').css('background-color'),
                   $('#wrong_m').css('background-color'),
                   $('#wrong_l').css('background-color'),
                   $('#na_h').css('background-color'),
                   $('#na_m').css('background-color'),
                   $('#na_l').css('background-color')];

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(color_range);
//d3.selectAll("svg > g > *").remove();

var svg = d3.select( d3.selectAll("#d3select")[0].pop() ).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var yBegin;

var innerColumns = {
  "column1" : ["Correct H","Correct M","Correct L"],
  "column2" : ["Wrong H","Wrong M","Wrong L"],
  "column3" : ["NA H","NA M","NA L"]

}


  var columnHeaders = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Section"; });
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Section"; }));
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var yColumn = new Array();
    d.columnDetails = columnHeaders.map(function(name) {
      for (ic in innerColumns) {
        if($.inArray(name, innerColumns[ic]) >= 0){
          if (!yColumn[ic]){
            yColumn[ic] = 0;
          }
          yBegin = yColumn[ic];
          yColumn[ic] += +d[name];
          return {name: name, column: ic, yBegin: yBegin, yEnd: +d[name] + yBegin,};
        }
      }
    });
    d.total = d3.max(d.columnDetails, function(d) { 
      return d.yEnd; 
    });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Section; }));
  x1.domain(d3.keys(innerColumns)).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
     return d.total; 
   })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".7em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("");

  var project_stackedbar = svg.selectAll(".project_stackedbar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Section) + ",0)"; });

  project_stackedbar.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.columnDetails; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return x1(d.column);
         })
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(d.yEnd); 
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return y(d.yBegin) - y(d.yEnd); 
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

but in v4 when I am making changes then no error is occurring but the graph is also not showing. The new code I am using is

```
var margin = {top: 4, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - 12*margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - 45*margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width-40], 0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x0)

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var color_range = [$('#correct_h').css('background-color'),
                   $('#correct_m').css('background-color'),
                   $('#correct_l').css('background-color'),
                   $('#wrong_h').css('background-color'),
                   $('#wrong_m').css('background-color'),
                   $('#wrong_l').css('background-color'),
                   $('#na_h').css('background-color'),
                   $('#na_m').css('background-color'),
                   $('#na_l').css('background-color')];

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(color_range);
//d3.selectAll("svg > g > *").remove();

var svg = d3.select("#d3select").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var yBegin;

var innerColumns = {
  "column1" : ["Correct H","Correct M","Correct L"],
  "column2" : ["Wrong H","Wrong M","Wrong L"],
  "column3" : ["NA H","NA M","NA L"]

}


  var columnHeaders = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Section"; });
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Section"; }));
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var yColumn = new Array();
    d.columnDetails = columnHeaders.map(function(name) {
      for (ic in innerColumns) {
        if($.inArray(name, innerColumns[ic]) >= 0){
          if (!yColumn[ic]){
            yColumn[ic] = 0;
          }
          yBegin = yColumn[ic];
          yColumn[ic] += +d[name];
          return {name: name, column: ic, yBegin: yBegin, yEnd: +d[name] + yBegin,};
        }
      }
    });
    d.total = d3.max(d.columnDetails, function(d) { 
      return d.yEnd; 
    });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Section; }));
  x1.domain(d3.keys(innerColumns)).rangeRound([0, x0.range()]);

   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
     return d.total; 
   })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".7em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("");

  var project_stackedbar = svg.selectAll(".project_stackedbar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Section) + ",0)"; });

  project_stackedbar.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.columnDetails; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return x1(d.column);
         })
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(d.yEnd); 
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return y(d.yBegin) - y(d.yEnd); 
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

data from the problem is

```
var data = [
  {
    "Section": "Quant",
    "Correct H": 1, "Correct M": 1, "Correct L": 3, "Wrong H": 2, "Wrong M": 3, "Wrong L": 5, "NA H": 2, "NA M": 4, "NA L": 3

  },
  {
    "Section": "PS",
    "Correct H": 1, "Correct M": 1, "Correct L": 3, "Wrong H": 2, "Wrong M": 3, "Wrong L": 5, "NA H": 2, "NA M": 4, "NA L": 3
  },
  {
    "Section": "Verbal",
    "Correct H": 1, "Correct M": 1, "Correct L": 3, "Wrong H": 2, "Wrong M": 3, "Wrong L": 5, "NA H": 2, "NA M": 4, "NA L": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: I changed several things... Always inspect the console. There were a lot of NaNs.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, you gonna write that up as an answer?

Comment: In my last graph i was able to put graph on two separate div with same id but i think this is not the case with this.

Comment: @Mark, nope, I'm too lazy... feel free to write it :-) It was basically the syntax for the scales.